# Python: Split list in subsets if the current element is minor than previous element

Tags: python, algorithm, list, list-comprehension, subset

I have the following python list:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

I am looking for a efficient way to split a list in several sublist only if the current element is minor than the previous element.

In the example, I should get:

```
result = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

I should get three subsets since 1<3 and 1<2.

I am only getting the first elements with this solution:

```
[[x] for index, x in enumerate(my_list) if index < 1 or x < my_list[index - 1]]
```

Result:

```
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

Another try with the same result:

```
[ [my_list[x]] for x in range(len(my_list)) if my_list[x] < my_list[x-1]]
```

Comment: the result is because you are only entering the value when the condition is met that is when 1 comes in your case

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I only fetch then the break points as I see in other responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a comprehension-ish approach.  But while you *could* cram this into one long expression, why on Earth would you want to?

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
>>> brks = [i for i in range(1,len(my_list)) if my_list[i] < my_list[i-1]]
>>> [my_list[x:y] for x,y in zip([0]+brks,brks+[None])]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

This works simply by finding the points where a new group begins and using those to slice into `my_list`.

Comment: Well, thinking in comprehension could not be the best focus for this problem, but I was trying to figure if I could achieve something with it. Marking your answer as more near to my solution, but other solutions really works for me too

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use a simple list comprehension to do this. A simple way would be the normal for loop method -

```
new_list = []
prev = float('inf')
for x in my_list:
    if x < prev:
        temp = []
        new_list.append(temp)
    temp.append(x)
    prev = x
```

---

Demo -

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
>>> new_list = []
>>> prev = float('inf')
>>> for x in my_list:
...     if x < prev:
...         temp = []
...         new_list.append(temp)
...     temp.append(x)
...     prev = x
...
>>> new_list
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

Timing comparisons of different methods given here -

Code -

```
from itertools import groupby

def func1(my_list):
    new_list = []
    prev = float('inf')
    for x in my_list:
        if x < prev:
            temp = []
            new_list.append(temp)
        temp.append(x)
        prev = x
    return new_list


def func2(my_list):
    brks = [i for i in range(1,len(my_list)) if my_list[i] < my_list[i-1]]
    return [my_list[x:y] for x,y in zip([0]+brks,brks+[None])]

def func3(my_list):
    return [list(next(g)) + [x[1] for x in g] for k, g in 
                  groupby(zip(my_list, my_list[1:]), lambda x: x[1] >= x[0]) if k]

def func4(my_list):
    results = []
    for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
        if i == 0:
            results.append([x])
            continue
        if x < my_list[i - 1]:
            results.append([x])
        else:
            results[-1].append(x)
    return results

import random
my_list = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Result -

```
In [20]: %timeit func1(my_list)      #Simple for-loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 236 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit func2(my_list)      #List comprehension using breaks.
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit func3(my_list)      #@Ashwini's One-liner
1000 loops, best of 3: 689 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit func4(my_list)      #@electrometro's approach.
1000 loops, best of 3: 407 µs per loop

In [31]: %timeit func1(my_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 223 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit func2(my_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit func3(my_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 703 µs per loop

In [34]: %timeit func4(my_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 415 µs per loop
```

Comment: Interesting way to do it.

Comment: This was my first way to focus this, but I was trying for avoid the normal loop/condition and store for this.

Comment: What is the problem with normal loop/condition?

Comment: No problems witn normal loop/condition, just trying my skills with python and as far I see it is the more efficient way in time spent

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution. You can convert it to a list comprehension if you would like but it would be a rather ugly one.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]

results = []
for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    if i == 0:
        results.append([x])
        continue
    if x < my_list[i - 1]:
        results.append([x])
    else:
        results[-1].append(x)

print results
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3])

print(np.split(my_list, np.where(np.diff(my_list) < 0)[0] + 1))
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```